# getContextMenuItems doesn't match on my grid?

Tags: ag-grid

see my page at : http://plus2value.fr/actions/action_display_angular
and please answer me why the contextmenu doesn't match ?

Comment: because you aren't on the enterprise edition. Context menu is only available with the enterprise edition, otherwise it's just a filter section

Comment: tks :)
and how can I upgrade to the enterprise edition ? is it free ?

Comment: no it is not free, pricing can be found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/license-pricing.php).