# ag-grid right click functionality

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Just want to ask, with ag-grid (MIT license), can I add a func to have row right click to show the context menu? I know the ag-grid-enterprise has contextMenu feature with commercial license. Is it allowed if I don't use enterprise version and develop the right click func ?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is already given here: [getContextMenuItems doesn't match on my grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868819/getcontextmenuitems-doesnt-match-on-my-grid)

> Context menu is only available with the enterprise edition, otherwise
>   it's just a filter section

(no accepted answer here so can't close this one)